# Vuetify 2.2.20 datatable row per page position error

Tags: datatable, vuetify.js

selector is in the wrong position compared to the table. how can i adjust this ?

[image]

> export default {
>               data() {
>                 return {
>                 search: '',
>                 headers: [
>                     {text: 'Id', align: 'start', sortable: false, value: 'id' },
>                     { text: 'Nome', value: 'name' },
>                     { text: 'Usuário', value: 'username' },
>                     { text: 'E-mail', value: 'email' },
>                   ],
>                 };
>               },
>               created(){
>                 this.$store.dispatch('loadUsersData')
>              },
>               computed:{
>                   users(){
>                       return this.$store.state.datatableusers.items
>                   }
>               },
>             }

Comment: Error is in your html content, please add the HTML code to your question or create a codepen.

Comment: This must be mainly something to do with your styling or some other library styling 
try inspecting to see the exact html elements with the issue and see whether any  of your styles contradict the element styling